# new object in for loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I'm getting mad with this piece of code:

```
for (int h = 0; h < invocations; h++)
{
    Filter newFilter = new Filter();
    newFilter = customFilter;
    newFilter.DateFrom = customFilter.DateFrom.AddDays(h*8);
    newFilter.DateTo = newFilter.DateTo.AddDays(8).AddSeconds(-1);
```

**customFilter is an object of type Filter**
customFilter is as an object which has about 10 properties inside it correctly filled. I need to create a new object but I've to change just two of these 10: DateFrom and DateTo.
The problem is that after the assignment of newFilter.DateFrom and newFilter.DateTo, also the customFilter.DateFrom and customFilter.DateTo change.
Could someone help me?

Bye
M.

Comment: customFilter is object. Hence references are playing here

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Could you help me about how get rid off this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newFilter` simply a variable. I'm assuming `Filter` is a class; in which case, when you do this:

```
Filter newFilter = new Filter();
newFilter = customFilter;
```

you can **forget** about the `new Filter()` - you've just dropped that somewhere on the floor, inaccessible from anwhere: you have set `newFilter` to be a reference to the **existing** object, via the existing reference `customFilter`.

`newFilter` and `customFilter` are now references **to the same object**.

I suspect you just need to remove the line:

```
newFilter = customFilter;
```

leaving just:

```
Filter newFilter = new Filter();
// set all properties on newFilter
```

or make it cloneable:

```
Filter newFilter = customFilter.Clone();
// set just the properties that need changing on newFilter
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line `newFilter = customFilter;` and copy each property by hand.

The above line copies the reference in `customFilter` to the `newFilter` variable, replacing the new Filter you just created. `newFilter` and `customFilter` points to exactly the same object after this operation.

Comment: It should be an idea because are "only" 10 properties. But, hypotethically, there's another way to solve it in case the object is more complex?

Comment: You could use reflection to copy the properties or use a tool like automapper that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning:

```
newFilter = customFilter;
```

the two references `newFilter` and  `customFilter` point to the same object!

Answer (score 0):

You are not copying customFilter's properties, you are assigning newFilter a reference to the same object as customFilter (assuming you have declared `Filter` as `class`) .

You could create a copy constructor and create your object from this:

```
public Filter(Filter template) {
    this.Prop1 = template.Prop1;
    this.Prop2 = template.Prop2;
    // etc.
}
```

then use it like this:

```
Filter newFilter = new Filter(customFilter);
```

Or you could provide a `Clone()` method in the `Filter` class that returns a clone:

```
public Filter Clone() {
    Filter result = new Filter();
    result.Prop1 = this.Prop1;
    result.Prop2 = this.Prop2;
    // etc.
    return result;
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
Filter newFilter = customFilter.Clone();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you make a reference to customFilter, with your newFilter in the line  4